# How to get the top 5 max values from a list using java stream

Tags: java, mapreduce, java-stream, reduce, collect

I have a list of Integer

```
List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<>();
lst.add(10);
lst.add(15);
lst.add(16);
lst.add(8);
lst.add(100);
lst.add(1);
lst.add(40);
```

How to write a code so that I can get the top 5 max element from the list, namely `100, 40, 16, 15, 10`?

I have tried by using Java stream API:

```
Integer var = lst.stream().max(Integer::compare).get();
```

but get only one value element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have tried by using Java stream API, but get only one value,
>
> Integer var = lst.stream().max(Integer::compare).get();

This will get you the max value of that list. To get the top 5 you have to do the following:

```
lst.stream()
   .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
   .limit(5)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The method [sorted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) will sorted in ascending order, as one can read on:

> sorted() Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream,
> sorted according to natural order.

However, we can use `sorted(Comparator<? super T> comparator)` which:

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, sorted
> according to the provided Comparator.

Therefore you need to pass [Comparator.reverseOrder()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort in descending order. The `limit(5)` will extract you the first 5 elements from the stream.

A more *generic* method:

```
private static void printTop(Collection<Integer> col, int top) {
    List<Integer> collect = col.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).limit(top).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(collect);
}
```

A running example:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    List<Integer> lst = List.of(10, 15, 16, 8, 100, 1, 40);
    printTop(lst, 5);
}

private static void printTop(Collection<Integer> col, int top) {
    List<Integer> collect = col.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).limit(top).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(collect);
}
```

Output:

```
[100, 40, 16, 15, 10]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<>();
lst.add(10);
lst.add(15);
lst.add(16);
lst.add(8);
lst.add(100);
lst.add(1);
lst.add(40);
List<Integer> lst1 = lst.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).limit(5).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(lst1);
```

this can help you in getting the top 5 max elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your List and then pop the last 5 elements or the first 5, depending on the way you've implemented the Comparable method.

Answer (score 1):

*get the 5 max-values in natural order*
*both works for*  list-size < 5  *w/o exception*

with a lambda *(as OP wanted)*

```
int[] n = {0};
List<Integer> rslt = lst.stream().sorted().dropWhile(
  i -> n[0]++ < Math.max(0, lst.size() - 5) ).collect( toList() );
```

with collection methods

```
lst.sort( Integer::compare );
List<Integer> rslt = lst.subList( Math.max(0, lst.size() - 5), lst.size() );
```